# How do I add the newsletter checkbox to the registration page?

Tags: magento-1.9

The newsletter checkbox does not appear on the registration page. How can I make it display when a new customer registers?

Comment: Update:

I have tried editing all the regist‌​er.phtml files I could find an not one made any change on the frontend. I have deleted the cache every time before testing.

Comment: check my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your `regist‌​er.phtml` file in your theme.

```
/app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/default/template/customer/form/regist‌​er.phtml
```

template file

```
<?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path and write some code

`/app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/customer/form/regist‌​er.phtml`

Find this line:

```
<?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
```

Right below it, add this:

```
<?php
$checked = true;
if($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) {
if(!$this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()) {
    $checked = true;
    }
}   
 ?>
```

Then Find this div

```
<div class="input-box">
```

Replace the code in the div with this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed" checked="checked" class="checkbox" />
```

And you will get more information see this link

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906602/magento-newsletter-auto-checked-on-registration-page**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...